# Creating a ProtoBuf Object in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

How do I properly instantiate a Protobuf model in C++?

```
msg::MyModel* model;

model->set_name("Red");
```

I am getting this error:

```
 undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
```

Comment: What is your full compiler command line? It looks like you aren't linking against libprotobuf (missing `-lprotobuf`).

Comment: This may well be it.  I used fedoras package man to install protobuf 2.5 but compiled 2.6.1 from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to make sure to add the Protobuf C++ file to the those passed to the compiler.